# Parsing arguments in fish shell without argparse

Tags: fish, fish-argparse

I'm using fish shell and wrote my own little parser function because I found argparse confusing. Basically, if a flag is matched, it uses the information from the following argument. However, I'm assuming my method must introduce bugs as I haven't seen this method used online. Are there advantages to using argparse that I'm missing?

```
function check_args
 
  for current_arg in (seq 1 (count $argv))

    #grab next argument
    set next_arg $argv[(math $current_arg + 1)]

    switch $argv[$current_arg]
    case -h --help
      usage
      break
    case -t --theme
      echo "theme: " $next_arg
      set -g theme themes/$next_arg.css 
    case -f --format
      echo "format: " $next_arg
      set -g format $next_arg
    case -o --output
      echo "output: " $next_arg
      set -g output $next_arg
    end
  end
end

check_args $argv #calls the function with the passed arguments
```

Comment: Some of the advantages of using `argparse`: it's already very well tested, it doesn't force you to only use options that take an argument, you can smush short arguments together (`-abc` or `-a -b -c`)

Comment: Could you show me what my example would look like using argparse? My method doesn't force you to only use options that take an argument by the way, unless i'm misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: I designed and wrote the `argparse` command implementation precisely because your approach doesn't behave like the standard option parsing that people expect. Your approach may be fine if you only need a subset of the usual argument parsing features but why do it the hard way?

Comment: I'd love to see how to do it in argparse! What would that code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With argparse:

```sh
# the -- is required!
argparse h/help t/theme= f/format= o/output= -- $argv
or exit 1

# just to inspect the variables
set -S _flag_h _flag_help _flag_t _flag_theme _flag_f _flag_format _flag_o _flag_output

if set -q _flag_help
    usage
    exit
end

set theme themes/$_flag_theme.css
set format $_flag_format
set output $_flag_output
```